# How to load date into pickadate using $_REQUEST in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, datepicker

I have an implementation of [amsuls pickadate plugin](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) . I have created the following form incorporating the pop up date picker:

[image: Form, from and to input fields]

When I choose a value for both of the pickdates, I want to be able to submit the form, but use the `$_REQUEST['input_value_from']` and `$_REQUEST['input_value_to']` values to load the dates back into the form. If the user for e.g. forgets to fill in another part of the form.

I had a look at the set method which is stated [here](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api.htm#method-set-select)

My current html is:

```
<div class="section__block section__block--scoped">
    From:
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="x_date_from" id="input_from" data-value="<?=$_REQUEST['x_date_from'];?>">
    </fieldset>
    To:
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="x_date_to" id="input_to" data-value="<?=$_REQUEST['x_date_to'];?>">
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

My current js is:

```
var $input_from = $('#input_from').pickadate();
var picker_from = $input_from.pickadate('picker');
picker_from.set('select', $('#input_from').attr("data-value"));

var $input_to = $('#input_to').pickadate();
var picker_to = $input_to.pickadate('picker');
picker_to.set('select', $('#input_to').attr("data-value"));
```

with the relevant pickadate scripts

```
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/lib/picker.js"></script>
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/lib/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/lib/picker.time.js"></script>
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/lib/legacy.js"></script>
<script src="/x/js/calendar/pickadate.js-3.4.0/demo/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which date picker library are you using? This one? http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/

Comment: Yes sorry, will edit question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading the page, you can pass the PHP variable to the initialize method of the pickadate() function.

```
$('#input_from').pickadate({
    <?php echo "select: [" . $_REQUEST['input_value_from'] . "]";?> //Format[yyyy,m,d]
})
```

Format $_REQUEST['input_value_from'] in the form of yyyy,m,d.

Final code used was:

a function:

```
$from_split = getYearMonthDayFromDate($_REQUEST['x_date_from']);
```

then adjusted the js to look like this:

```
var $input_from = $('#input_from').pickadate();
var picker_from = $input_from.pickadate('picker');
picker_from.set('select', [<?php echo $from_split['year'].','.$from_split['month'].','.$from_split['day']; ?>]);
```

Comment: Where is this "now:" in the [API](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api.htm)? I thought it was "set"..

Comment: I think it's "now:", I found it in the source: https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/blob/gh-pages/lib/picker.date.js

Set is also possible in the same manner if it's the correct attribute.

Edit: It seems that there isn't a defined function for setting a value.

Comment: picker_from.set('select', [date.getFullYear() + 1, date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate() + 1]); This works, but I cant get my PHP to work within it. Can you see whats wrong with this - `//picker_from.set('select', <? echo '['.$from_split['year'].','.$from_split['month'].','.$from_split['day'].']'; ?>);`

Comment: You open PHP tags with <?php, not <?

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark question as answered.